# AWS SDK SQS client acknowledgement

Tags: amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-js, aws-java-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am working on a consumer in my NodeJS application that would receive messages from SQS and then process them.

Here is the eaxmple from AWS SQS JS SDK V3:

```
// Import required AWS SDK clients and commands for Node.js
import { ReceiveMessageCommand } from  "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";
import { sqsClient } from  "./libs/sqsClient.js";

// Set the parameters
const queueURL = "SQS_QUEUE_URL"; // SQS_QUEUE_URL
const params = {
  AttributeNames: ["SentTimestamp"],
  MaxNumberOfMessages: 1,
  MessageAttributeNames: ["All"],
  QueueUrl: queueURL,
  WaitTimeSeconds: 20,
};

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await sqsClient.send(new ReceiveMessageCommand(params));
    console.log("Success, ", data);
    return data; // For unit tests.
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
};
run();
```

In my case, the part where I process the message is very I/O intensive, so I want my `process()` function to be executed asynchronously, but then, as the last step, I want to perform an acknowledgement:

```
const run = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await sqsClient.send(new ReceiveMessageCommand(params));
    prosessData().finally((data) => ack(data));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
};
run();
```

As far as I understand, the acknowledgement is done automatically here... And I wasn't able to find a configuration setting that would tweak this behaviour.

However, in Java API, there is such capability, it is called "client acknowledge mode", how do I achieve a similar behaviour in JS?

How would the `prosessData().finally((data) => ack(data));` look like ?